# Any good approximation for this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, improper-integrals

I am interested in the following integral $$
\mathcal{I}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathop{dz}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+b}(z^2)^{n/4}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+b\cos^2\theta}(R^2+z^2)^{n/4}}\right],
$$
where $R\ll 1$, $n<2$ and $$\cos\theta=\frac{z}{\sqrt{R^2+z^2}}.$$ I was thinking of Taylor Expanding the integrand for $z<R$, and integrating the result from $-R$ to $R$, but the answer seems not good when compared numerically. Any good approximation if not the exact answer would work. Any ideas? Thanks

Note that for $b=0$, an exact expression for the above integral exists and is given by
$$\mathcal{I}=-\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma[n/4-1/2]}{\sqrt{a}\Gamma[n/4]}R^{1-n/2}.$$

Comment: The function has a closed form anti derivative in terms of Appell F1 function.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: What are the constrains on $a$ and $b$? Is $n>0$?

Comment: Yes. $0<n<2$, and $a>0$ and $a+b>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Not an aswer, just some simplifications of the original problem.

Let's call $n/2=s \in (0,1)$, and do some elementary transformations:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cdots=2 \int_0^\infty \cdots$$

$$\frac{R}{z}=u$$

$$1-s=q \in \left(0,1 \right)$$

$$p^2=\frac{a}{a+b} \in \left(0, \infty \right)$$

If $b>0$ then $p^2 \in \left(0,1 \right)$.

> $$I=\frac{2R^q}{\sqrt{a+b}} \int_0^\infty \frac{du}{u^{q+1}} \left(1-\sqrt{\frac{(1+u^2)^q}{1+p^2 u^2}} \right)$$

There's no $R$ inside the integral now, and we are left with $2$ parameters. However, it's still quite complicated to get a general approximation, using Taylor series, because the ranges of $u$ and $p$ are the same, and we probably need to consider $4$ separate cases for each of them being in $(0,1)$ or $(1, \infty)$.