# Limit with the Appell F1 function

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals, special-functions

While attempting to solve [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1596641/any-good-approximation-for-this-integral) problem I ran into a nasty limit.

Mathematica claims that the indefinite integral

$$\int\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+b}(z^2)^{n/4}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+b\cos^2\theta}(R^2+z^2)^{n/4}}\right]\,dz
$$

where $$\cos\theta = \frac{z}{\sqrt{z^2+R^2}}$$

is equal to

$$-\frac{z \left(R^2+z^2\right)^{-\frac{n}{4}} \left(\frac{z^2}{R^2}+1\right)^{\frac{n+2}{4}} \sqrt{\frac{a \left(R^2+z^2\right)+b z^2}{R^2+z^2}}}{a (a+b) \sqrt{\frac{z^2 (a+b)}{a R^2}+1}}-\frac{2 z \left(z^2\right)^{-\frac{n}{4}}}{(n-2) \sqrt{a+b}}\cdot\left[b F_1\left(\frac{1}{2};\frac{n+2}{4},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2};-\frac{z^2}{R^2},-\frac{(a+b) z^2}{a R^2}\right)+a F_1\left(\frac{1}{2};\frac{n+2}{4},-\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2};-\frac{z^2}{R^2},-\frac{(a+b) z^2}{a R^2}\right)\right]$$

With the restrictions $a>0$, $b>0$, $0<n<2$ and $R\ll 1$.

We want the definite integral from $-\infty $ to $\infty$ and because the function is even we can take the difference of the limits at infinity and $0$. Mathematica evaluates to limit at $0$ to be equal to zero but isn't able to evaluate the upper limit.

In an effort to make the arguments of the Appell functions converge to something I applied the following transformation ([citation](http://functions.wolfram.com/07.36.17.0001.01))

$$F_1\left(a;b_1,b_2;c;z_1,z_2\right)\to\left(1-z_1\right){}^{-b_1} \left(1-z_2\right){}^{-b_2} F_1\left(c-a;b_1,b_2;c;\frac{z_1}{z_1-1},\frac{z_2}{z_2-1}\right)$$

Which simplifies to

$$\lim_{z\to\infty}z\left(\frac{\left(R^2+z^2\right)^{-\frac{n}{4}} \sqrt{a+\frac{b z^2}{R^2+z^2}}}{(a+b) \left(z^2 (a+b)+a R^2\right)}+\frac{2 \left(z^2\right)^{-\frac{n}{4}}}{(n-2) \sqrt{a+b}}\left[b R^2 F_1\left(1;\frac{n+2}{4},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2};\frac{z^2}{R^2+z^2},\frac{(a+b) z^2}{a R^2+(a+b) z^2}\right)+\left(z^2 (a+b)+a R^2\right) F_1\left(1;\frac{n+2}{4},-\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2};\frac{z^2}{R^2+z^2},\frac{(a+b) z^2}{a R^2+(a+b) z^2}\right)\right]\right)$$

The arguments now converge to 1, but mathematica claims that the limit is complex infinity which I know not to be true because the integral converges for the special cases that I have tried numerically. Where is my mistake? The transformation seems valid because the only restriction is that $$z_1, z_2\not\in(1, \infty)$$ which is clearly the case. Do I need more restrictions to ensure convergence?

**Edit:** Using the comment from Pierpaolo Vivo the limit in question becomes

$$\lim_{\zeta\to\infty}\left[\frac{\zeta  \sqrt{\frac{\zeta ^2}{\alpha ^2}+1}}{\sqrt{\alpha ^2+\zeta ^2}}+\frac{2 \zeta ^{1-\frac{n}{2}}}{n-2}F_1\left(\frac{1}{2};\frac{n-2}{4},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2};-\zeta ^2,-\frac{\zeta ^2}{\alpha ^2}\right)\right]$$

When I apply the same transformation as above we obtain

$$F_1\left(\frac{1}{2};\frac{n-2}{4},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2};-\zeta ^2,-\frac{\zeta ^2}{\alpha ^2}\right)=\frac{\left(\zeta ^2+1\right)^{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{4}}}{\sqrt{\frac{\zeta ^2}{\alpha ^2}+1}}F_1\left(1;\frac{n-2}{4},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2};\frac{\zeta ^2}{\zeta ^2+1},\frac{\zeta ^2}{\alpha ^2+\zeta ^2}\right)$$

The limit now becomes

$$\lim_{\zeta\to\infty}\left[\zeta  \left(\frac{\left(\zeta ^2+1\right)^{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{4}} F_1\left(1;\frac{n-2}{4},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2};\frac{\zeta ^2}{\zeta ^2+1},\frac{\zeta ^2}{\alpha ^2+\zeta ^2}\right)}{\sqrt{\alpha ^2+\zeta ^2}}+\frac{2 \zeta ^{-\frac{n}{2}}}{n-2}\right)\right]$$

Now mathematica evaluates the limit to be $0$ at both end points..... I feel like there has to be something flawed with these transformations but all the given criteria are met. What's going on here?

Comment: Just a comment. It seems your original integral (from $-\infty$ to $\infty$) can be rewritten in the much neater form
$$
\frac{2 R^{1-n/2}}{\sqrt{a+b}}\int_0^{\infty }\zeta ^{-\frac{n}{2}}  \left(1-\frac{\zeta ^{n/2} \left(\zeta ^2+1\right)^{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{4}}}{\sqrt{\alpha ^2+\zeta ^2}}\right) \, d\zeta
$$
where $\alpha^2 = a/(a+b) $. (I have checked with Mathematica). Still Mathematica is unable to compute it, but provides a primitive in the form of a nicer AppellF1. Thought it might help.

Comment: Another small comment. My impression is that one should just forget the Appell beast altogether. Using the integral representation for the Appell in <http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/AppellF1/07/01/01/0001/> and after a few rearrangements, I think I am able to reformulate the problem in the following way. The value of the integral
$$
I = \int_0^{\infty }\zeta ^{-\frac{n}{2}}  \left(1-\frac{\zeta ^{n/2} \left(\zeta ^2+1\right)^{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{4}}}{\sqrt{\alpha ^2+\zeta ^2}}\right) \, d\zeta
$$
is equivalent to

Comment: $$
I = \lim_{M\to +\infty}\left\{-\frac{M}{2 \alpha}\left[\int_0^1\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}}(1+t M^2)^{\frac{2-n}{4}}\left(1+t\frac{M^2}{\alpha^2}\right)^{-1/2}-\frac{4\alpha}{2-n}M^{-n/2}\right]\right\}
$$
(checked with Mathematica, say, for $n=1.5$, $\alpha=0.8$ and $M=5000$). [Ask in a comment if you need more details]. You might want to repost another question in the 'limit' section, there are wizards out there ready to jump in ;-).

Comment: Thanks for all the reformulations! I'll have a go at the integral representation.